# Animate rotation on "CSS3"

Tags: jquery, html, css

If I have this [box](http://jsfiddle.net/fud4n/2/) in CSS3 (also if, for what I understand, this is not CSS3, just browsers specific) :

## HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box">&nbsp;</div>
</div>    ​
```

## CSS

```
#container
{
    padding:100px;
}

#box
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
}

#box.selected
{
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Opera */
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Firefox */        
}
​
```

## jQuery (just for manage the hover on the box)

```
$('#box').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
);
```

how can I set an animation to that css rotation? I mean, not in 1 step, but fluid. So the moviment should be "animate". Hope you understand what I mean :)

Comment: you can rotate it with css itself ...

Comment: hey now check to this http://jsfiddle.net/fud4n/12/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you just want to apply an animation to the transformation, you can use CSS3 transitions, specifically `transition-property` (defines which properties will have a transition) and `transition-duration` (to specify the duration of the transition from start to completion). There is also `transition-timing-function`, which allows you to use any of the following modes of transition: `linear|ease|ease-in|ease-out|ease-in-out|cubic-bezier(n,n,n,n)`

```
#box
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    /* Explicit above, can also use shorthand */
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    /* Also shorthand with the easing-function */
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

See my revision to your jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/fud4n/9/

Comment: You should really use the short form of the properties. The code in your answer is really redundant.

Comment: @Codemonkey Yes hence the shorthand of the `-ms-` version, I was simply verbosely demonstrating the properties :) I will update the others to be shorthand also.

Comment: Well! My problem is with a rotation fixed point : http://jsfiddle.net/fud4n/13/ it make a strange effect, doesnt rotate "around" that point

Comment: @rudi_visser Better yet, remove the Jquery altogether and use the CSS pseudo-class ":hover" as in [this modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fVYV/)

Comment: @markzzz I think it's because the origin point will also be animated since it's on the hover state, apply it to #box directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/) like so:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: with transform-origin it doesnt works as well : http://jsfiddle.net/fud4n/10/ (i make some strange "movement" around the fixed rotation point) :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/fud4n/18/

It's important to remember to but the origin and transition properties in the class/id of the element you're trying to animate, not the class representing the animated state.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS3 animation like so: http://jsfiddle.net/fud4n/15/ (example given for firefox only). This will perform a continuos rotation, just change the duration as you prefer.

```
#box.selected {    
    -moz-animation-name: rotation;  
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;  
}

@-moz-keyframes rotation {
    from {  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);  }      
    to   {  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);  }
}
```